# HTML text, set same value to hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

In laravel, I have some heading text being populated with data from the controller but I want to set the exact same fields in the heading to hidden inputs for form submission.

I'm trying the code below, and the data shows properly in the h2 tags, but I'm trying to set each one to its own hidden input field and I'm trying to do a console.log to make sure I'm setting them but it's not showing anything in the console.

I'm not sure if I'm messing up at setting the hidden input or maybe I'm just not establishing the variables or logging them correctly.

ANy ideas? Thanks

```
@foreach($items as $item)

    <form id="testForm">

        <h2>{{$item->id}}</h2>
        <h2>{{$item->name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{$item->category}}</h2>

        <input type="hidden" name ="id" id = "id" value="{{$item->id}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name ="name" id = "name" value="{{$item->name}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name ="category" id = "category" value="{{$item->category}}" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
           var id = $("#id").val();
           var name = $("#name").val();
           var category = $("#category").val();

           console.log(id);
           console.log(name);
           console.log(category);

        </script>

    </form>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but do you have jQuery installed in your project ? Or a script with jQuery CDN in your code ? Do you have the values in your displayed html ? (Inspect elements or try the same code in web browser console) ?

Comment: IDs **have** to be unique per document, which is not the case as you are assigning the same ID in each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give unique name for each hidden fields.

```
@foreach($items as $item)

    <form id="testForm">

        <h2>{{$item->id}}</h2>
        <h2>{{$item->name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{$item->category}}</h2>

        <input type="hidden" name ="id_{{$item->id}}" id = "id_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->id}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name ="name_{{$item->id}}" id = "name_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->name}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name ="category_{{$item->id}}" id = "category_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->category}}" />               

    </form>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the name and value to the Form::hidden() method.

```
{{ Form::hidden('id', $item->id, array('id' => 'id')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('name', $item->name, array('id' => 'name')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('category', $item->category, array('id' => 'category')) }}
```

Comment: I'm testing this now. How can I properly dump this in the console?

Comment: same way you have done in your example. just use Form:hidden() instead of input type='hidden'. Just to make sure it has value. But for usability you need to have different ids and names for each element